# Powershell: undelete messages removed by recipient policy

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, powershell, outlook

A specific recipient policy was mistakenly applied to all mailboxes in our company.  I have changed the recipient policy to the correct one. I now need to restore (from delete items) all messages that that were affected by that recipient policy.

These users have many subfolders and I don't want to open outlook and use "recover deleted items" on each folder.

How can I recover deleted messages from all folders in a given mailbox?  Can I constrain it by date deleted?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Search-Mailbox`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298173.aspx) cmdlet to search for items deleted today, and copy them back.
**NOTE: I haven't tested this yet, so please follow all three steps and make sure it acts as expected!**

Perform a search on a Test Mailbox and review the output:

```
Get-Mailbox "Test Mailbox" | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'modified:(today)' -SearchDumpsterOnly -EstimateResultOnly
```

Perform a search again on a Test Mailbox and verify that messages deleted today were moved back

```
Get-Mailbox "Test Mailbox" | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'modified:(today)' -SearchDumpsterOnly
```

Perform the search on all mailboxes and emjoy!

```
Get-Mailbox | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'modified:(today)' -SearchDumpsterOnly
```

I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Search-Mailbox does not support the modified property unfortunately